# Bell curve calculation and sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create bell curve report from the follwing data.
[image]

how to calculate amount produced from monday to sunday for each day of week report from above data.

Below is the output I am expecting

[image]

Data display according to datetime.

Comment: can u post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking for a grouping on day of week, of the entire dataset, you can use the below query:

```
select
    wk.dow      [day of week]
    , d.rt      [day Total]
from
(select datename(weekday, createdon) dow
    , sum(qty) rt
from table d
group by datename(weekday, createdon)) d
    right join (select 'Monday' dow
                union all 
                select 'Tuesday'
                union all
                select 'Wednesday'
                union all
                select 'Thursday'
                union all
                select 'Friday'
                union all
                select 'Saturday'
                union all
                select 'Sunday') wk on d.dow = wk.dow
```

Although I hafe a feeling you're looking for this query:

```
select datepart(week, createdon)        [week nr]
    , datename(weekday, createdOn)      [day of week]
    , dd.rt                             [running total]
from table d
    cross apply (select sum(qty) rt from table dd where dd.createdOn <= d.createdOn) dd
order by createdon
    , datepart(week, createdon)
```

Comment: thank you for reply @Radu Gheorghiu ....but which formula of bell curve and how to apply on above data to get expected output??? I make bell curve report for given data how to do that??

Comment: @dhirenpatel I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do here. Do you want a SSRS report which displays a bell curve of the data?

Comment: yes i get bell curve report based on above data.. how to apply sql query to get expected output??

Comment: @dhirenpatel Well, that is a totally different question and context than what you have posted in your above question. I don't know how to make a SSRS report like that.

Comment: Okay..thank you ... if u have any resource that i can find that report???

Comment: @dhirenpatel I don't. I suggest you do a web-search for this information and if you don't find anything then you can come back to Stackoverflow and ask another question, only on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

for 2012 version

```
SELECT FORMAT(B,'dddd') , sum(a) as toalamount
FROM #A
GROUP BY FORMAT(B,'dddd')
```

in place of b u need to replace with createdon and a with qty
then u will get above result

Comment: thank you for reply @chanukya....but which formula of bell curve and how to apply on above data to get expected output??? I make bell curve report for given data how to do that??